# use i18next offline and without webserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got an offline js app.
Now my customers wants me to translate it into another language.

My plan is to use i18next but it requires a JSON file.
When I check it in Firebug it does a GET request.

We have to keep it offline no matter what... 
Can I use i18next offline without a web-server on all common browsers?

Thanks

**[This is i18n](http://i18next.com/)**

Comment: *runs in browser, under node.js, rhino and other javascript runtimes.*

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yea I'm just not sure because it did a get request, are you 100% sure that I can run it offline?

Comment: Your description suggests you have tested the library though a web server. Under those conditions, there's no other way it can fetch files than HTTP. Why don't you test it in your real target environment?

Comment: You can run without webserver but some browser dosenot loads the JSON in file protocol, it needs http protocol for Ajax

Comment: @powercoder23 Thanks for the tip, do you know which browsers?

Comment: I'm willing to accept your comment as an answer @powercoder23, since your post lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works.
On Firefox it works as default.

on Chrome you have to start it like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it works. Just add the json file in the cache manifest, and the browser will have in in the application cache.